# Call jquery plugins whenever a plugin is called

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have 3 jquery plugins - fixheadertable, jqTransform and facebox. Whenever fixheadertable plugin is called other two plugins are not working.

So i have to call those two plugins after each call of fixheadertable.

This is happening because fixheadertable recreates the table rows whenever i sort or use pager. So the plugins used in those table rows are not working.

The important thing is jqTransform and facebox should be applied only inside the table where fixheadertable plugin is applied. Otherwise facebox displays the content twice on overlay.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    $('.alter').fixheadertable({ 
    height : ($(window).height()- 200), 
    colratio : [30, ,50, 50], 
    zebra : true, 
    sortable : true,
    resizeCol : true,
    pager : false }); 

    $('form').jqTransform({imgPath:'../../assets/includes/formplugin/img/'});
    $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
});
```

Edit :

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/rQXtZ/6/

First click edit link. And then click on country to sort. Again try edit link. now facebox will not work

Comment: I find myself having difficulty understanding what you need.  Are you saying the  plugins need to be called and are not, or are you saying that they are just not getting called only inside of the fixheadertable plugin?  Or something else?

Comment: all the plugins are working fine in the begining. And then when i use fixheadertable, the other plugins used inside the table where fixheadertable called, are not working. Outside the table those are woking.

Comment: You could look at the source code/documentation of the fixheadertable plugin and see if it fires any event after sorting... so you could listen to the event and reapply the other plugins

Comment: @Michi: I am not able to find such event in fixheader table. Here is the js file https://raw.github.com/benjaminleouzon/tablefixedheader/master/javascript/jquery.fixheadertable.js

Comment: You could insert it yourself. Nearing end of file, after the last if clause insert $(this).trigger('fixheadertable:done')... then listen for that event from your code

Comment: @Michi: Thank you. But how to listen for the event. can you explain with sample

Comment: $('.alter').on('fixheadertable:done',function(e){$('form').jqTransform({imgPath:'../../assets/includes/formplugin/img/'}); $('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();});